# Calling redux sagas sequentially

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

Saga noob here. I tried to find the right way of doing this but am unable to come up with anything that solves my problem.

I have a saga that makes an API call to get a decision. Based on the decision, I may do a redirect or dispatch another action that triggers another saga flow.

```
export default function* applicationFlow(action) {
  let data = { productInfo: {} };
  try {
    yield put(appStatusSwitch('busy', 'Processing', 'app-status.text.verifying'));

    const res = yield call(api.call, data);

    const decision = res.decision ? res.decision.toLowerCase() : null;

    yield put(appDecision(decision));

    switch (decision) {
      case 'question':
          yield put (appQuestions (res.questions));
          // redirect to questions page
          redirectTo ('/question-page');
        break;
      case 'pass':
      case 'fail': 
        //dispatch an action that does another flow..yield takeLatest(APP_SUBMIT, processApplicationFlow)
        yield put (submit ());
        break;
      default:
        redirectTo('/technical-difficulty');
    }
  }
  catch(e) {
    redirectTo('/technical-difficulty');
  }
  finally {
      yield put(appStatusSwitch('free'));
  }
}
```

In the flow above, how do I make the saga wait for the `yield put(submit())` to complete before the flow in this generator goes on to the `finally` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you could `call` the `processApplicationFlow` saga directly instead of putting an action.

Your `case` would look like this:

```
case 'fail':
  yield call(processApplicationFlow)
  break
```

`call` will block until the other saga is finished.

I hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: If `processApplicationFlow` is already a saga, so a generator, can't we just do `yield processApplicationFlow()`? Why do we still have to wrap it with a `call`?

Comment: Thanks Alex, but then how come you did a call above? Still trying to grasp this stuff.

Comment: Just by habit :)